# SQL error connecting to database - WAMP

Tags: sql, wamp, connect

I have WAMP installed. I am trying to connect the database and it will not work.
I have all services started... I created a test file calledtes44.php and put it in the WWW folder to see if it wpuld work

The code is

```
 <?php phpinfo() ; ? >
```

When I run that file in browser I receive the error...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\wamp1\www\test44.php
>   on line 1

What am I missing??

James

Answer (score 1):

You have a space at the end tag.
Try it like this:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong quotes. 
Use this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "membersapp") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Instead of this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(“localhost”,””,””,”membersapp”) or  die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Also, add a semicolon at the end of your echo:

```
echo "Connected to database";
```

Comment: just to update, i connected, i was missing the name root :) thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be it:

```
// The connection string
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "membersapp");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    // Error! 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    // Woohoo, success!
    echo "Connected succesfully!";
}
```